# Strange 301 redirect needed .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, jpeg, http-status-code-301

I have a website that has recently been getting a bit busy. I put out a free demo version of an app I made that got a lot of downloads. A 600kb file generated 110GB of traffic per day after about 1 day. So I successfully made a redirect to another server for all files with htaccess like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.mydomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/myfolder/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

So that is fine and my server is much less busy. But I make a machine that gets art and backgrounds for various screens off the server as well so that I can add new images whenever I want and the machines will all download/cache/display them. I am doing this with just directory listing enabled. They are all jpg. I anticipate a surge in traffic for this soon as well so I want to store the images in an amazon aws S3 bucket. I can access the images no problem using direct linking. But I need my machines to see a directory listing which I found out amazon doesn't really do. I have directory listing working with a script but it only seems to work in a computer web browser.  That brings me to my strange request.

Is there a way to keep all my customer machines getting directory listing from hxxp://mydomain.com/folder but the 301 redirect only kicking in when a jpg is downloaded?

So the machines see the listing off the old server but when a file is downloaded

1.jpg = new host
2.jpg = new host

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?subdomain.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\.jpe?g)$ http://newdomain.com/myfolder/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have mentioned all the images were in subdirectories in the subdomain so I made one .htaccess file in each subfolder to redirect them to their respective subfolders inside the S3 bucket like this   

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?subdomain.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\.jpe?g)$ https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/S3bucket/subfolder/$1 [L,R=301,NC]`